# jquery slideToggle css top position

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have figured out how to move my css top position with jquery however I would like the #menu id to change top position based on the toggle. So Basically I want the #menu to drop 50 px when the anchor is clicked and slide back up 50px when the anchor is clicked again, but currently it only moves down and stays down, not sure how to accomplish this. Im close I know it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#menu a').click(function() {
  $('#menu').css("top","50px");
  $('#navResponsive').slideToggle('fast', function() {
  });
});

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.toggle()` instead of the `.click()` on the link.

```
$('#menu a').toggle(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#menu').animate({top: '50px'}, 'slow');
},function(event){  
    event.preventDefault();    
    $('#menu').animate({top: '0px'}, 'slow');
});
```

What this will do is move the menu down 50px on the first click and then bring it back up on the second click. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/dxrz6/) that shows this.